# Countdown Timer not counting correctly

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown

When I pause the timer and then start it again it seems like the timer counts the current second again. For example it is 00:10, after half a second I stop the timer and when I start it again instead of going from 00:10 to 00:09 in half a second it counts a full second. I can't find what is wrong. Thanks for any help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer_2);   
    //...
     Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
     buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
           public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                            
            if (timer_2_up_running) {
                pausetimer_2_up();
                starttimer_2_down();

            } else {
                starttimer_2_up();
                if (timer_2_down_running) {
                    pausetimer_2_down(); 


private void starttimer_2_up() {
    timer_2_up_countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(starttimeup, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            starttimeup = millisUntilFinished;
            update_up_text();          

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer_2_up_running = false;

        }
    }.start();

    timer_2_up_running = true;
}

private void starttimer_2_down() {
    timer_2_down_countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(starttimedown, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            starttimedown = millisUntilFinished;
            update_down_text();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer_2_down_running = false;

        }
    }.start();

    timer_2_down_running = true;
}

private void pausetimer_2_up() {
    timer_2_up_countdowntimer.cancel();
    timer_2_up_running = false;
}

private void pausetimer_2_down() {
    timer_2_down_countdowntimer.cancel();
    timer_2_down_running = false;
}

private void update_up_text() {
    int minutes_up = (int) (starttimeup / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds_up = (int) (starttimeup / 1000) % 60;
    String time_2_up_left_formatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes_up, seconds_up);
    timer_2_up.setText(time_2_up_left_formatted);
}

private void update_down_text() {
    int minutes_down = (int) (starttimedown / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds_down = (int) (starttimedown / 1000) % 60;
    String time_2_down_left_formatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes_down, seconds_down);
    timer_2_down.setText(time_2_down_left_formatted);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use Chronometer to display recording time. start the
>   Chronometer when recording start and stop it when recording stop

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometerRecordTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout_bottom_video_controls"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>


private Chronometer chronometerRecordTime;

chronometerRecordTime = findViewById(R.id.chronometerRecordTime);

chronometerRecordTime.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()); // Reset
chronometerRecordTime.start(); // start

chronometerRecordTime.stop(); // stop
```

Comment: Could you explain it a little more pls

Comment: with the help of chronometer, we can show the timer on UI, i have use this on one of my app to show recording time, it will automatically get update we just need to start, stop and reset it. the following link explain it more .  http://abhiandroid.com/ui/chronometer

Comment: The problem is that i want it to count backwards,from starttime to 0

Comment: this is not possible with chronometer, it starts from 0 and we need to stop it,

Comment: Is there another way without using the chronometer that solves my problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I have also crate timer to stop recording after one min. you can
>   modify it according to your requirement.

```
    int myTimeCounter;
    Timer myRecordingTimer;
    private boolean myTimerHasStarted = false;
    private String TAG = "Log";
    private void startTimerTask() {
        myTimeCounter = 1;
        myRecordingTimer = new Timer();
        myRecordingTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        myTimerHasStarted = true;
                        if (myTimeCounter == 60) {
                            myRecordingTimer.cancel();
                            myTimerHasStarted = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "timer=" + String.valueOf(myTimeCounter));
                        myTimeCounter++;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```